# responsive not full width when loading single page

Tags: css, responsiveness

I am trying to make a responsive website, but I am stumbling upon a weird problem. When I am looking on the desktop page, everything is in the right position. There are no pixels left.

However, when I am loading the responsive version on my mobile, I see some pixels left (just scroll to the left or the right and you will see what I mean). The problem gets bigger when there is content like a single post or page.

The website is here: http://FavoriteFM.com.

I can provider the CSS code, but it will be a lot of lines. I am suspecting something in the content is 'sticking out'. But I am not sure of a tool that can see such problems.

Thanks,
Dennis

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: share the image to show us where are the pixels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I have disabled every div by div. I figured out the problem is with the sidebar. I still had: 'left: 8px;' on. Removing it did the trick for me. So if you have this problem, check if something of your content is 'sticking' outside your wrapper. Even if you can't see it, it still can be there.